# MongoDB retrieve all keys with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

From my research I have only found solutions that either:

[Are outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection?rq=1) - and db.runCommand do not work in node.js as below link:

[Can't get to work within node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086961/getting-keys-columns-of-collection-in-mongodb-nodejs)

[Don't list all sub/nested keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/using-map-reduce-for-mapping-the-properties-in-a-collection) (see problem in answer)

I also wonder if it possible to now do with the Aggregation Framework...?

Seems to be quite a known feature missing from MongoDB...

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem here?
Can you add some details to that?

Comment: Nothing outdated about it. Even the latest release cannot do anything more than list the top level keys only. The correct solution is **still** to use `mapReduce()`. It's also not a "feature" with as much utility as you seem to think it has.

Comment: And perhaps you might try [reading the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#mapReduce).

Comment: db.runCommand does not work on node.js

Comment: Also, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335469/run-map-reduce-for-all-keys-in-collections-mongodb 

The aggregation framework may be faster...?

Comment: Why do you need `runCommand` if there's a native [`mapReduce`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#mapReduce) method available in the driver?

Comment: becuase when i try with: result = db.COLLECTION.mapReduce( I get a type error: cannot read property 'mapReduce' of undefined

Comment: Please look specifically at the example code for `mapReduce` to find out why that won't work.

Comment: Now I just get: cannot read property result of undefined. I could post my code but it doesnt format correctly in comments i dont think... I have tried combining the example you linked to and the marked duplicate solution. Maybe its dto do with mapreduce not returning the result globally? I dont know :L

Comment: I also needed to include the "out" part which was not in the original solution something like this: mr = coll.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: {inline:1},verbose:true})